# Core Data unable to generate where clause for predicate (Swift)

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a Core Data managed object with an NSNumber property (stored as Integer 64). I'm attempting to retrieve an object using a predicate object as follows:

```
let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "MyEntity")
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "pageId == %@", pageId)
```

when then causes the following run-time error :

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to generate where clause for predicate (pageId == 22205021) (unknown problem)'
```

where the pageId is "22205021" in this instance. As far as where clauses go it looks OK, namely, `pageId == 22205021` so I don't understand why it won't work.

*Note*: I'm using Xcode 7 beta 4.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually this turned out to be my fault - I was using a non-existent property for that object in the predicate. "MyEntity" did not contain a "pageId" - a better error message would not go amiss though.

Answer (score 2):

`pageId` may not actually be an NSObject when in Swift.

Try `NSPredicate(format: "pageId == %d", pageId)`.

That uses an integer to compare and not an NSNumber.

Comment: Good suggestion but unfortunately that fails with the same error. I also tried string interpolation ```pageId == \(pageId)``` but that fails in exactly the same way. I've also asked on the Apple forums and will post any info here. If all else fails I'll raise a bug report.

Comment: Interpolation I've seen documented as the wrong way to do it (don't have reference handy)

Comment: Yeah, I agree, it has security implications. I just wanted to see if it would still crash in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted looks correct to me.  If the code works in the previous Xcode and there's no other changes (except for conformance) I'd consider that it may be a reportable bug.

Comment: The equivalent code (minus the try/catch stuff) does work in Xcode 6.4 so it may indeed be a bug.

Comment: An experiment might be to remove the try / catch, if the compiler allows it).

Comment: Unfortunately the compiler does not allow running the fetch request outside the try/catch block